# Accessing/reading JSON hierarchy

Tags: arrays, json, loops, hierarchy

I am trying to get access a list of contacts via JSON. I am having difficulty understanding the JSON Hierarchy and accessing the objects:

```
$token="25948503485mytokenhere003403403";
$url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Accounts/getRecords?";
$url .= "authtoken=".$token."&scope=crmapi";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$contacts = json_decode($json);

$cleanObj = $contacts->response->result->Accounts->row;

function getCompany($obj, $part) {
    $innerObj = $obj->FL;
    foreach ($innerObj as $c)  {
        if ($c['val'] == $part) {
            return $c['content'];
        }
    }
}

$company = getCompany($cleanObj[0], "Company");

echo "<pre>";
print_r($cleanObj);
echo "</pre>";
```

Here is the raw response to show you the hierarchy:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [no] => 1
        [FL] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 1900238000000115001
                        [val] => ACCOUNTID
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 1900238000000097003
                        [val] => SMOWNERID
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => chase
                        [val] => Account Owner
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => Test Company
                        [val] => Account Name
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => www.google.com
                        [val] => Website
                    )

                [5] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 0
                        [val] => Account Number
                    )

                [6] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 0
                        [val] => Employees
                    )

                [7] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 0
                        [val] => Annual Revenue
                    )

                [8] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 0
                        [val] => SIC Code
                    )

                [9] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 1900238000000097003
                        [val] => SMCREATORID
                    )

                [10] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => chase
                        [val] => Created By
                    )

                [11] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 1900238000000097003
                        [val] => MODIFIEDBY
                    )

                [12] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => chase
                        [val] => Modified By
                    )

                [13] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 2016-05-18 13:50:57
                        [val] => Created Time
                    )

                [14] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 2016-05-18 13:50:57
                        [val] => Modified Time
                    )

                [15] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 0
                        [val] => Billing State
                    )

                [16] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 2016-05-18 13:50:57
                        [val] => Last Activity Time
                    )

            )

    )
```

I am trying to access the fields like "ACCOUNTID" "SMOWNERID" "Account Owner" "Account Name" etc on that level.

This code is returning the error "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array":

```
$company = getCompany($cleanObj[0], "Company");
```

Can someone please help me access each contacts object and be able to loop through and output them?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. Used:

```
$co_name = $contacts->response->result->Accounts->row->FL[3]->content
```

as the path to the Company

Turns out result->Leads had to be changed to result->Accounts to get it to read properly.